# QNX Neutrino 6.5.0 LAN communication

Tags: windows, lan, simulator

I have two PCs. 1) Console (Windows based), connected with 2) Qnx Neutrino 6.5.0(Simulator) using Ethernet cable. I want to send data from PC1-Console to PC2-QNX Neutrino 6.5.0 using LAN cable. What is the simplest way to do this communication? Is it possible to do using command window?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Qnx Software development platform 6.6 from Qnx site as per windows/ Linux os
2. Install
3. Create project
4. Window menu , Target option
5. Enter host name and IP address
6. You can access data from Qnx

Answer (score 0):

You can get an ftp server on the QNX system running.
First you need to configure your interface. The interface name can be gathered by running 'ifconfig', in vmware it's 'en0'.

Now set the IP address:

```
# ifconfig en0 192.168.0.2
```

Enable the ftp and telnet services:

1. Edit /etc/inetd.conf and make sure ftp and telnet are uncommented.
2. If you want to login as root remove the root user from /etc/ftpusers
3. Run inetd from the command line.

From the windows box, assuming the interface has a 192.168.0.x address you can now ftp or telnet to the QNX target.